# Google Cloud Platform quota increase for personal project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using Google Cloud with personal account. My quota increase request was constantly denied without giving any reason. I contacted Google Cloud Support and they referred me to the sales team. However, the sales team said they only handle quota increase request for business account users. I am not sure what to do next, can someone give me a pointer? I have paid 3 months without any issue with credit card. Thanks a lot! Here are some sample quota increase requests that I got rejected:
[image: cpu_quota_request]
[image: ip_quota_request]

Comment: A quota increase is the same as a credit line increase. How long have you had your account? How many months have you paid without issues? Which quotas are you trying to increase? In my experience, you will need to wait for at least three paid billing cycles.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I just added screenshots of my rejected quota requests. Could you help me take another look? Thanks!

Comment: We cannot help you convince Google to increase your quota. As I mentioned, you must wait at least three months. It could be much longer. There are many factors that go into evaluating a customer's credit worthiness.

Answer (score 1):

Usually quota's are set as reasonable limits for new accounts that don't have much spend as you begin to start using the platform.

If your account is new, I would recommend to start using the services for at least one billing cycle to demonstrate your usage, and then after some time, request additional quota.

You haven't given much information in your question unfortunately, so I don't know which quota you're referring to, but in general the quotas are there to prevent spam and abuse from Google's side, and bill-shock and accidents from the customer side.

Alternatively, you can always open a billing support ticket asking for a quota increase, and ask if there's a monetary component you can put down into your account to prove your serious about the extra resources. This proves to Google that you're serious about the implications of cost and that you're aware of what your doing by putting money forward.

Either way a billing support team member will be able to help you, if you're serious about it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I just added screenshots of my rejected quota requests. Could you help me take another look? Thanks!